# is my usage of a php semaphore really threadsafe?

Tags: php, concurrency, semaphore

We have a php script that is executed by a dhcp server on certain events.
These events can occour very often if there are many users and because the script has certain dependencies it can only be excecuted one by one. To achieve this we use a semaphore and this is how it is implemented.

```
public function getGlobalLock() {
    $this->semaphore = sem_get($this->sem_key, 1, $this->sem_perm, 1);
    if(!$this->semaphore) {
        // throw exception because we always should be able to do this!
        // this is a serious error
        throw new Exception("Error. Locking was not possible, unable to retrieve semaphore key. PID " . $this->pid . ", purpose for lock is: " . $this->purpose);
    }
    // blocks while waiting for semaphore
    if(!sem_acquire($this->semaphore)) {
        // throw exception because we always should be able to do this!
        // serious error
        throw new Exception("Error. Locking was not possible, unable to acquire semaphore. PID " . $this->pid . ", purpose for lock is: " . $this->purpose);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that we have some problems with the script behaveing odd and one thought is that the semaphore isn't working like we expect it to do.
Can anyone verify that this should guarantee a sequential order?

Comment: it's simple to test. Write a test where you take the semaphore and go to sleep some seconds. In the meanwhile another call tries to get it.

Comment: In fact we did test it and we didn't find any failures on this, but we thought that this is maybe just because we were lucky, and to verify this would cost a lot of time and effort. So if there is anyone who already put thoughts into this it could help.